# Missing Right Parenthesis while using sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence, parentheses

```
CREATE TABLE customer_master(
    cust_id NUMBER(6) CUSTOMER_SEQ.Nextval PRIMARY KEY,
    cust_password VARCHAR2(10),
    cust_fname VARCHAR2(30),
    cust_lname VARCHAR2(30),
    cust_gender VARCHAR2(8),
    cust_dob DATE,
    cust_email VARCHAR2(30),
    cust_password VARCHAR2(30),
    cust_mobile NUMBER(10),
    cust_add VARCHAR2(100),
    newsletter VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (newsletter IN('yes','no')),
    mob_service VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (mob_service IN('yes','no'))
);
```

Comment: 1. Please specify SQL server model and version. 2. Try to use its shell or analog which exposes an error place (at least, line number).

Comment: @Netch It's Oracle because of VARCHAR2 and Nextval. Anyway he supposed to mention it.

Comment: @Netch  sorry for that.
and thanks for helping....you are so F1full......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use trigger.

```
   CREATE TABLE customer_master(
      cust_id NUMBER(6)  PRIMARY KEY, 
      cust_password VARCHAR2(10),
      cust_fname VARCHAR2(30),
      cust_lname VARCHAR2(30),
      cust_gender VARCHAR2(8),
      cust_dob DATE,
      cust_email VARCHAR2(30),
      cust_mobile NUMBER(10),
      cust_add VARCHAR2(100),
      newsletter VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (newsletter IN('yes','no')),
      mob_service VARCHAR2(5) CHECK (mob_service IN('yes','no'))
    );

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  INS_customer_master
    BEFORE INSERT ON customer_master
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        i_LAST NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT CUSTOMER_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO i_LAST FROM Dual;
        :NEW.cust_id := i_LAST;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: @Akbarali You can insert whatever you want on cust_id  and it will be replaced by tirgger's value from sequence. In example `INSERT INTO CUsTOMER_MASTER VALUES(1, '123','akbarali','kharodia','male',to_DATE('16/12/1991','dd/mm/yyyy'),'ak‌​barali@gmail.com',9558815440,'Gnagar','yes','no') `

Comment: INSERT INTO CUsTOMER_MASTER VALUES('123','akbarali','kharodia','male',to_DATE('16/12/1991','dd/mm/yyyy'),'akbarali@gmail.com',9558815440,'Gnagar','yes','no')


Not enough values...
i dont wants to pass NULL everytime...can i automate it?